# zabbix server won't start

Tags: db2, schema, centos6, zabbix, db2-luw

I compile zabbix 3.2 on centos (with db2)

when I enable "DBSchema" configuration (in zabbix_server.conf) the zabbix_server can not start.

I change the debug level of zabbix server to 5 and the result is :

```
tail -f /var/log/zabbix_server.log
  4293:20170108:082441.986 In DBcheck_version()
  4293:20170108:082441.986 In DBconnect() flag:0
  4293:20170108:082441.998 query without transaction detected
  4293:20170108:082441.999 query [txnlev:0] [set current schema='ZABBIX']
  4293:20170108:082441.999 End of DBconnect():0
  4293:20170108:082441.999 query [txnlev:0] [select 1 from syscat.tables where tabschema=user and lower(tabname)='dbversion']
  4293:20170108:082442.031 DBcheck_version() "dbversion" does not exist
  4293:20170108:082442.031 query [txnlev:0] [select 1 from syscat.columns where tabschema=user and lower(tabname)='config' and lower(colname)='server_check_interval']
  4293:20170108:082442.051 Cannot upgrade database: the database must correspond to version 2.0 or later. Exiting ...
  4293:20170108:082442.053 End of DBcheck_version():FAIL
```

i have no idea about this problem.

db2 configuration is set and every things is OK and web installation steps is pass but zabbix_server can not start

Comment: Did you load the default zabbix DB config? Sounds like there are no tables in the DB...

Comment: yes , the configuration is set and the 3 file "schema.sql" and "image.sql" and "data.sql" imported to db2 database

Comment: I have never used db2, but does the current user have the right to read the table syscat.tables? Zabbix apparently uses this, to identify the version of the databaseServer. Maybe you can connect as the zabbix user and query the table with the query: select 1 from syscat.tables where tabschema=user and lower(tabname)='dbversion'

Comment: yes
the user's access is OK
and tables is exist